# Why can't the curve with $\dfrac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt} =0$ be considered as smooth curve?

Tags: calculus, continuity, vectors, plane-curves, curves

The vector function is considered being smooth if the curve is continuous and the differential $\dfrac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt}$ is not $0$ at any point.

I can understand the first condition saying that the curve must be continuous but cannot understand how the differential $\dfrac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt}$ equals to $0$ makes the curve not smooth?

Will you help prove the notion for me?

Comment: Your definition of "smooth" looks wrong. Perhaps it says "...the curve is **continuously differentiable**..." instead of just "the curve is continuous"?

Comment: I use Thomas's Calculas Textbook and it's written in page 728 "A vector function r is differentiable if it is differentiable at every points of its domain. The curved traced by r is smooth if dr/dt is continuous and never 0..."
I doubt why dr/dt(the velocity vector) cannot be 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a picture of the curve parameterized by $t\mapsto (t^3,t^2)$:

[image]

Notice how this has a clearly visible point where its direction changes abruptly (a [cusp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity))). This is why one can have problems when the derivative goes to zero - basically, if the parameterization stops moving at some point, then it "forgets" about what came before, and can go off in whatever direction it pleases, creating corners and cusps. Thus, one has the requirement that smooth curves have a parameterization where the derivative does not go to zero anywhere.

Comment: In my classes, "smooth" meant something different when applied to functions compared to curves. A function was smooth if it is infinitely differentiable, while a curve is smooth if it is once differentiable with a non-zero derivative everywhere. So I don't think OP is misusing the term.

Comment: @5xum Huh. I've always seen curves described with the same terminology as functions. I didn't realize there were other conventions. I took that bit out my answer anyways.

Comment: So, judging from the graph here, if at a point of a graph being 0, it means that the graph will have *pointy* section which says that the parameter stop at that point. then it's not smooth. And if I'm not wrong the pointy there is indifferentiable. Is that another reason why it's considered as not smooth

Comment: @RexSolus If the derivative is zero it means that the graph *might* have a pointy section, which wouldn't have any geometrically meaningful derivative. A parameterization like $t\mapsto (t^3,t^3)$ gives a line (which is smooth), but the parameterization isn't a good witness to this, since it has a point where the derivatives go to zero. (Contrasted to the more usual parameterization $t\mapsto (t,t)$, which works fine)

Comment: "A parameterization like t↦(t3,t3)t↦(t3,t3) gives a line (which is smooth), but the parameterization isn't a good witness to this, since it has a point where the derivatives go to zero. " since the mentioned parameter has a point that detivatives go to zero, shouldn't it be considered as not smooth?

Comment: @RexSolus The curve it parameterizes should be considered smooth, since it has a (different) parameterization whose derivatives never go to zero. Note that the definition you gave from Thomas' Calculus Textbook refers to "the curve traced by $r$" being smooth rather than $r$ itself. That is, a curve is smooth even if *some* parameterizations have points where the derivative goes to zero, so long as there exists at least one parameterization whose derivative doesn't go to zero. That is the case with the parameterization I listed.