# smooth curve vs. piecewise differential curve

Tags: complex-analysis

In Chapter 4, page 45 of Bak's & Newman's "Complex Analysis" they define two concepts regarding curves: smooth curve and piecewise differential curve.

(a) We say that a function $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb C$, $\gamma(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$ is **piecewise differential curve** if $x'(t)$ and $y'(t)$ exist and continues for every $t\in[a,b]$ except for a finite number of points.

(b) We say that a piecewise differential curve $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb C$, $\gamma(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$ is **smooth** if $\gamma'(t)\neq0$ for every $t\in[a,b]$ except for a finite number of points.

My questions are:

**Q1**: Where in complex analysis the smoothness (as defined here) is important? In other words, why it is important to assume that $\gamma'(t)\neq0$? Are there any significant result that demand smoothness ?

**Q2**: Geometrically, piecewise differential curve means that our curve have at most finitely number of "corners". What is the Geometric meaning of smoothness as defined here?

Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882292/why-cant-the-curve-with-dfrac-mathrm-dr-mathrm-dt-0-be-considered-as-sm

Comment: This post is an illuminating example as to why we want curves to not have $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t$. Note that this is also necessary if we want an arc-length parameterization of our curve.

Comment: Thanks @ rubikscube09. You mean that unless $\gamma$ is smooth, the expression $\int_{a}^{b}|\gamma'(t)|dt$ will be problematic?

Comment: The arc-length parameterization involves the factor $1/|\gamma'(t)|$, which of course becomes problematic when $\gamma'(t) = 0$