# Why the first derivative has to be continuous for the graph of the function (not the function) to be smooth

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors

Assume $r(t)$ is a vector function of $t$, $f$, $g$ and $t$ are real function of $t$, and

$r(t) = f(t)\mathbf{i} + g(t)\mathbf{j} + h(t)\mathbf{k}$,

where **i**, **j**, **k** are standard unit vectors in three-dimensional coordinate system. Then on p.399 in the book "*Thomas' Calculus Early Transcendental*" (14th ed.), the author wrote:

> The curve traced by $r(t)$ is smooth if $dr/dt$ is continuous and never 0, that is, if $f$, $g$, and $h$ have **continuous** first derivatives that are not simultaneously 0. We require dr dt ≠ 0 for a smooth curve to make sure the curve has a continuously turning tangent at each point. On a smooth curve, there are no sharp corners or cusps.

My understand is that in order for the **graph** of a function to have no sharp corners, or cusps (the so-called *smooth* **curve** in the above paragraph) on a closed interval $[a, b]$, the function need only be differentiable at every point in the interval. So why did the author add the condition for the derivative to be continuous in the first place?

Comment: I accepted the answer here because of its trueness, for those who came across this question, you can also reference answer for this question with visual aided: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882292/why-cant-the-curve-with-dfrac-mathrm-dr-mathrm-dt-0-be-considered-as-sm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic counter-example is something like the function $f(x)$ which is $0$ for $x = 0$ and $x^2sin(1/x)$ for all other $x$.

The derivative exists everywhere (including $x = 0$), but isn’t continuous at $x = 0$ (because the $sin(1/x)$ term oscillates more and more rapidly as you approach zero, any interval around $x = 0$, no matter how small, will contain values of $f’(x)$ in the entire range of $[-1, 1]$)

As a result of this discontinuity of derivative, the graph of $f(x)$ is not smooth at $x = 0$ (the graph won’t approach a straight line in any interval around $x = 0$, no matter how small)